# Is using malloc within scanf compliant to c ansi standard

Tags: c, c89

I want to read the input of a user and save it. What i have now does work but i need to know if its legit (following ansi standard - c90) that scanf is first assigning the variable "length" before it allocates memory for the input,
or if its just a quirk of the compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char* text;
    int length = 0;
    scanf("%s%n", text = malloc(length+1), &length);

    printf("%s", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, the evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified, but `length` is filled during the call to `scanf()`, so you can only use it afterwards, hence this construct can never work at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but exactly that is what i don't understand. It does work with mingw as a compiler. But if it is unspecified thats all the answer i needed. Thanks

Comment: You pass a pointer to the length field to scanf. Scanf will fill it with the length of the string `%s`. So it is available _after_ you called scanf. But you have to allocate the space with `malloc()` _before_ the call to scanf. See the mismatch?

Comment: [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is nasty that way. Sometimes it might seem to work, but the next time (with maybe some small and seemingly irrelevant change) it will crash and burn.

Comment: *It does work with mingw as a compiler.* Only for very, very loose definitions of "work".  Since `length` is initialized to zero, your code allocates a 1-byte buffer to hold whatever string is read.  Reading anything longer than a zero-byte string will overflow that buffer and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: try piping in a few megabytes of data (with no spaces)

Comment: out of all what was already said your program follows a very strange logic, the first thing to get is the string and the second its length, the logical order is to get first the length then the string

Comment: @bruno But with scanf() the `%n` _must_ be after the `%s` to have the parameter filled with the string length.

Comment: Even if `length` was somehow set earlier, using the result of `malloc()` before you've tested whether it's null is far too dangerous to consider.

Comment: @Ctx the logic is read the length, malloc and check malloc result, then read the string

Comment: @bruno Hehe ;) How do you expect to read the length without reading the string? ;))

Comment: @ctx of course the length must be available before the string, the logical way must be on both side ^^

Comment: "I want to read the input of a user and save it" - and you expect that user will count his characters and enter the correct value? What for user interface.

Comment: There is no need for you to write such a confusing code. Just write clear structured code and move on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will **not** work as you expect.

At the time you call `malloc`, `length` still has the value 0, so you're only allocating one byte.  `length` isn't updated until after `scanf` returns.  So any non-empty string will write past the bounds of the allocated buffer, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

While not *exactly* the same, what you can do is use `getline`, assuming you're running on a POSIX system such as Linux.  This function reads a line of text (including the newline) and allocates space for that line.

```
char *text = NULL;
size_t n = 0;
ssite_t rval = getline(&text, &n, stdin);

if (rval == -1) {
    perror("getline failed");
} else {
    printf("%s", text);
}
free(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the obvious problem with misuse of `scanf` addressed in another answer, this doesn't follow any C standard either:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
text = malloc(length+1)
```

Since you didn't include `stdlib.h` where `malloc` is found, C90 will assume that the function `malloc` has the form `int malloc(int);` which is of course nonsense.

And then when you try to assign an `int` (the result of malloc) to a `char*`, you have a constraint violation of C90 6.3.16.1, the rules of simple assignment.

Therefore your code is not allowed to compile cleanly, but the compiler must give a diagnostic message.

You can avoid this bug by upgrading to standard ISO C.

Answer (score 1):

Issues well explained by others

> I want to read the input of a user and save it

To add and meet OP's goal, similar code could do

```
int length = 255;
char* text = malloc(length+1);
if (text == NULL) {
  Handle_OOM();
} 
scanf("%255s%n", text, &length);

// Reallocate if length < 255 and/or 
if (length < 255) {
  char *t = realloc(text, length + 1);
  if (t) text = t;
} else {
  tbd(); // fail  when length == 255 as all the "word" is not certainly read.
}
```

The  above would be a simple approach if excessive input was deemed hostile.

Comment: Though on modern hosted systems, 256 bytes is no big deal to allocate on the stack or as static memory, so there's no need to use malloc here in the first place. On modern embedded systems, malloc shouldn't be used either, for other reasons.

Comment: @Lundin I'd expect OP is allocating as part of a read-string/word function and needs to return allocated memory.   True a `char text[2555+1]` would work fine if all uses of `text` were local.